# Does Chrome work with --enable-udd-profiles on Windows7?

Tags: google-chrome, user-profiles

When enabled (chrome.exe --enable-udd-profiles) hitting **Ctrl+M** brings dialog that allows to start another Chrome thread with different user profile. I use that on Windows Vista. Now I'm sitting on Windows 7 and I'm unable to make that work.

Could anyone confirm please whether that does work on Windows7?

Comment: --enable-udd-profiles right?

Comment: oh yes, double-typo, i mean 'udd', sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like they've long removed this feature to keep things consistent. You can try using the UserProfile switch though: `--user-data-dir="C:\Path\to\Profile"`

Comment: thanks, i know of this switch, i just find Ctrl+M super-comfortable, now seeing they have removed this option makes wanna scream... why ffs? lately Chrome kinda pi**** me off :(

Comment: With a new version coming out every 6 weeks, it should pi$$ you off less every month.

Comment: Well, I don't suppose this shortcut will make it back. It is rather the 'wont-fix' attitude of Chromium developers sometimes what is annoying on this awesome browser: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8022